# C# Not Reading my Input

Tags: c#, .net

Im trying to save a path into my input varaible, but its not reading my input! Im debugging and its completely skipping the line!

```
public static void OpenFile(int FileSize)
    {
        char GetLines = ' ';
        char[] FileContents = new char[FileSize];

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Path Name: ");
        GetLines = (char)Console.Read();
        GetLines = (char)Console.Read(); // Getting No Input Y?

        StreamReader MyStream = File.OpenText(GetLines.ToString());


        while (GetLines != null)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(FileContents);
          GetLines = (char)MyStream.Read(); 
        }
        MyStream.Close();


    }
```

Everything else works fine. This function is being called in Main...
My Goals is still to try and read the contents of the file into an array.

THIS IS NOT A HOMEWORK ASSIGNMENT! =)

Comment: As a char, GetLines can never be null, so your while-loop never ends. The compiler probably issued a warning about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal using Console.Read().
Read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use Console.ReadLine() and MyStream.Readline() ?

Here is a StreamReader example:

```
public class ReadTextFile
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a File Path:");
        string fileName = Console.Readline();
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName);
        string input = reader.ReadLine();
        while (input != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            input = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        reader.close;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to try Console.ReadLine().

As it is, you are reading the second char that the user enters, and treating that as a path name.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void OpenFile(){
    string path;
    while(true){
        Console.Write("Enter a path name: ");
        path = Console.ReadLine();
        if(File.Exists(path))
            break;
        Console.WriteLine("File not found");
    }

    string line;
    using(StreamReader stream = File.OpenText(path))
        while((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
            Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

If you need the entire contents of the file in a string, change the latter part of the function to:

```
    string file;
    using(StreamReader stream = File.OpenText(path))
        line = stream.ReadToEnd();
```

If what you really need is a byte array, use:

```
    byte[] file; 
    using(FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(path)){
        file = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(file, 0, file.Length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to use `Console.Read`? It will read the next character from the input (1 character that is). If you instead use [`Console.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) it will read a full line.

Also, in your code above `GetLines` will contain only the second character of your input, if I interpret it correctly (the second `Console.Read` line will replace the contents of the `GetLines` variable).

Answer (score 0):

Console.Readline() is probably what you need. Console.Read() reads a single character.

Also, your while loop has an issue. A char will never be null, as it is a value type.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) of Console.Read for how it behaves.

Let's say you want to enter 'a' and 'b' as consecutive inputs. Console.Read blocks if there are no characters in the stream  - it doesn't return till the user presses Enter (at which point it adds a OS-dependent end-of-line delimiter (\r\n for Windows).
So let's say you input `a[Enter]`

```
GetLines = (char)Console.Read();  // blocks till you press enter (since no chars to read) - contains 'a' (97)
GetLines = (char)Console.Read();  // doesn't block reads \r (13) from the stream 
GetLines = (char)Console.Read();  // doesn't block reads \n (10) from the stream
```

Instead If you input `abc[Enter]` for the first Read(), GetLines would contain a, b and c respectively.

As others have pointed you probably want ReadLine() which behaves more intuitively.